# html "left" attribute in different screens

Tags: html, css

I want to make like facebook notification list ("see image below") 
Or stackoverflow notification

[image]")

**But when i change the *left* values in css it change in different screens (wide or normal) **

What to do , please check the code below

the html code is

```
<div style="float:right;text-align:right;margin-right:10px;width: 113px;">
    <a  class ="notifications" >
        Press here
    </a>
</div>

<div id="notificationRegionWrapper" style="margin-left: 0px;  left: 0px;">
    <div id="notificationRegion" class=""><div id="notificationDropHeader">
            <div id="notificationDropHeaderText" style="padding-top: 6px;">
                Notification List 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="notification_item" style="opacity: 1;">
            <div class="notification_item_desc">
                <p class="notification_item_title">
                    Test One
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

css is here

```
#notificationRegionWrapper{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px #888888;
    display: none;
    margin-left: 223px;
    max-height: 70%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 137px;
    width: 360px;
    z-index: 10;
     }

     #notificationRegion #notificationDropHeader {
    background-color: white;                    
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C5C5C5;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
#notificationRegion .notification_item {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #F9F9F9, #EBEDEE) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C5C5C5;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table;
    min-height: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
#notificationRegion .notification_item .notification_item_pic {

    float: right;
    height: 51px;
    margin: 12px;
    width: 51px;
}
#notificationRegion .notification_item .notification_item_desc {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0 0 1px;
    width: 77%;
}
#notificationRegion .notification_item .notification_photo {
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    height: 51px;
    width: 51px;
}
#notificationRegion .notification_item .notification_item_desc .notification_item_time {
    color: #777777;
    font-size: 10px;
    float: right;
}
```

***JQuery here :***

```
$(document).on('click',".notifications",function(){
     $("#notificationRegionWrapper").show();
    });​
```

Comment: Where are you declaring `left`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this would be to put `<div id="notificationRegionWrapper">...</div>` inside the div which contains the link to open the dropdown.

Then instead of using absolute positioning on `#notificationRegionWrapper` use relative positioning. That way the dropdown will always be positioned relative to the link and will like the same on all screen sizes.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/Eeqrm/

Notice you also need to give the parent div `position:relative;`.